# Do sending Data SMS have a size limit in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Text SMS have a limit of 160 characters and to send more than that you have to send using multipart SMS.

Is this applicable for Data SMS too? If the size of the data SMS exceeds (160 Characters * 7 (I believe each character is encoded using 7 bits), you have to split and send it?

I tried receiving a data SMS in the emulator, (sending a UTF-8 encoded String, using getBytes(),) however I was not able to convert back the message completely, the message is filled with different characters, when I try to get back the string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, sending and receiveing data SMS doesn't work well in emulator. You'll have to use real device.

From my experience, data SMS takes less than 140 bytes. I was trying to send ~140 bytes and I got exceptions.
I didn't have time to digg deeper what's the real limit of data SMS. If you find out, let me know.

data SMS have 133 byte capacity (140-7 byte for port number)